# CentOS 7 fullscreen not working in VirtualBox

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I installed CentOS 7 inside VirtualBox. Additionally, I installed virtualbox guest additions in the following way:

```
yum update kernel*
yum update
yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers dkms gcc gcc-c++
yum install epel-release
yum install dkms
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/rhel/virtualbox.repo
yum install libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel binutils patch make
yum install VirtualBox-5.0.x86_64
/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to get CentOS in fullscreen mode and I have two mouse pointers.[image]

How is it possible to get fullscreen and only one mouse pointer?

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualBox Guest Extensions](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/)

Follow that link, find your version of VirtualBox and I normally use the ISO and manually mount the CDROM drive under Linux and perform the install.  Never had luck installing from the EPEL